# Confusion as to how fork() and exec() work

Tags: unix, operating-system

Consider the following:

[image]

Where I'm getting confused is in the step "child duplicate of parent". If you're running a process such as say, skype, if it forks, is it copying skype, then overwriting that process copy with some other program? Moreover, what if the child process has memory requirements far different from the parent process? Wouldn't assigning the same address space as the parent be a problem?

I feel like I'm thinking about this all wrong, perhaps because I'm imagining the processes to be entire programs in execution rather than some simple instruction like "copy data from X to Y".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All modern Unix implementations use [virtual memory](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Virtual_memory). That allows them to get away with [not actually copying much](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Copy-on-write) when forking. Instead, their memory map contains pointers to the parent's memory until they start modifying it.

When a child process exec's a program, that program is copied into memory (if it wasn't already there) and the process's memory map is updated to point to the new program.

Answer (score 3):

[fork(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/fork.2.html) is difficult to understand. It is explained a lot, read also [fork (system call)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fork_%28system_call%29) wikipage and several chapters of [Advanced Linux Programming](http://advancedlinuxprogramming.com/). Notice that `fork` does *not* copy the running program (i.e. the `/usr/bin/skype` [ELF](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Executable_and_Linkable_Format) executable file), but it is lazily copying (using [copy-on-write](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Copy-on-write) techniques - by configuring the [MMU](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Memory_management_unit)) the [address space](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Address_space) (in [virtual memory](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Virtual_memory)) of the forking [process](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Process_%28computing%29). Each process has its address space (but might share some segments with some other processes, see [mmap(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/mmap.2.html) and [execve(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/execve.2.html) ....). Since each process has its own address space, changes in the address space of one process does not (usually) affect the parent process. However, processes may have [shared memory](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shared_memory) but then need to synchronize: see [shm_overview(7)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/shm_overview.7.html) & [sem_overview(7)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/shm_overview.7.html)...

By definition of `fork`, just after the `fork` syscall the parent and child processes have *nearly* equal state (in particular the address space of the child is a copy of the address space of the parent). The only difference being the return value of `fork`.

And `execve` is overwriting the address space and registers of the current process.

Notice that on Linux all processes (with a few exceptions, like kernel started processes such as `/sbin/modprobe` etc) are obtained by `fork`-ing -from the initial `/sbin/init` process of pid 1.

At last, [system calls](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/System_call) -listed in [syscalls(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/syscalls.2.html)- like `fork` are an elementary operation from the application's point of view, since the real processing is done inside the [Linux kernel](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linux_kernel). Play with [strace(1)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/strace.1.html). See also [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22883245/841108) and [that one](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11609768/841108).

A process is often some machine state ([registers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Processor_register)) + its address space + some kernel state (e.g. [file descriptors](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File_descriptor)), etc... (but read about [zombie processes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zombie_process)).

<sup>Take time to follow all the links I gave you.</sup>